# ImageView onClick need to click twice to perform an action

Tags: android, imageview, onclicklistener, cardview

I have set up [CardView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/CardView.html) in my app.The card has [ImageView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html) on it.I have set up `onClickListener` on [ImageView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html). But action is performed after clicking twice the [ImageView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html).
This is code for `CardView`:

```
<LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/assign"
                android:layout_margin="7dp"
                android:padding="15dp"
                android:layout_width="70dp"
                android:background="@drawable/circle"
                android:layout_height="70dp"
                android:src="@drawable/assign" />
                <TextView
                    android:text="Assign Table"
                    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                    android:id="@+id/textAssignTable"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/clear"
            android:src="@drawable/clear"
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

This is code for setting `OnCLickListener` for `ImageView`.

```
assign.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    String tag = "";
                    fm = getFragmentManager();
                    tx = fm.beginTransaction();
                    AssignTable table=new AssignTable();
                    tx.replace(R.id.frame, table, tag);
                    //tx.addToBackStack(tag);
                    tx.commit();
                }
            });
            clear.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    String tag = "";
                    fm = getFragmentManager();
                    fm.popBackStack();
                    tx = fm.beginTransaction();
                    tx.replace(R.id.frame, chooseTab, tag);
                    //tx.addToBackStack(tag);
                    tx.commit();
                }
            });
```

This is code for `OnClickListener` for `SwipeCardOnClick`

```
  @Override
            public void onItemClick(View view, int i)
            {
                clear=(ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.clear);
                phone=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.phone);
                assignTable=(ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.assignTable);
                textAssignTable=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textAssignTable);
                textAssignTable.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        String tag = "";
                        fm = getFragmentManager();
                        tx = fm.beginTransaction();
                        AssignTable table=new AssignTable();
                        tx.replace(R.id.frame, table, tag);
                        //tx.addToBackStack(tag);
                        tx.commit();
                    }
                });
                assignTable.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        String tag = "";
                        fm = getFragmentManager();
                        tx = fm.beginTransaction();
                        AssignTable table=new AssignTable();
                        tx.replace(R.id.frame, table, tag);
                        //tx.addToBackStack(tag);
                        tx.commit();
                    }
                });
                clear.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        String tag = "";
                        fm = getFragmentManager();
                        fm.popBackStack();
                        tx = fm.beginTransaction();
                        tx.replace(R.id.frame, chooseTab, tag);
                        //tx.addToBackStack(tag);
                        tx.commit();
                    }
                });
```

Comment: Is this on a physical device or emulator?

Comment: Physical Device

Comment: Are clear and assign is vector drawable image?

Comment: No. I have taken from Drawables

Comment: Tried this? Set `android:clickable="true"` `android:focusable="true"` to Imageview and `android:clickable="false"` `android:focusable="false"` to CardView

Comment: is it in a listview?

Comment: No. It is in SwipeCardView

Comment: Have you kept onClick listener on ListView item too?

Comment: Yes OnClick for SwipeCard.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you remove android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
or make it false.

This seems to consume the first click so not passing it on to the click listener.
The second click then succeeds as the focus is now obtained.
The other option is to set RequestFocus to true which will then set the focus so the first click will then not be consumed. 
I had a similar issue trying to keep button selected history using android:focusableInTouchMode="true". 
RequestFocus() then removed the 1st click  consumption issue.

I hope this makes sense.

Comment: Thanks, it really worked:)

Answer (score 0):

You can overwrite  
In first you can src blank image
For second you can src with color image
For both set on click listener so it will look like favourite button

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).